# How to manage redirect back to original URL in laravel passport Oauth2 flow

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I have an authenticating server (*auth-server*) running laravel passport, and another web application (*application B*) running on laravel using above auth-server to authenticate users using authorization code grant

Now what I want is to redirect user to the original url in application B after logged in using the auth-server. In oAuth2 flow in laravel passport, we can not send the originating url to the auth process or any extra parameters in that case, it only redirect the user to a pre-given path.

In application B side also I couldn't handle it since, after the redirection, laravel creates a brand new session.So there is no way for me to keep track of the original url.

So since I couldn't send the originating url to the auth-server and get it back from there, nor keep it in a session in application B, how could I keep track on the originating URL..? (Database also is not an option here)

Comment: _"after the redirection, laravel creates a brand new session"_ - on purpose, or rather by accident? If the latter, it could have to do with the `SameSite` setting of your session cookie.

Comment: @CBroe it is 'same_site' => 'lax'. I even tried changing it to `none`. Still no luck

Comment: That should be okay to pick up the session again in this scenario, I think. So is laravel deliberately destroying the current session and creating a new one then? Without giving you access to the value stored in the old session first? That would not make much sense IMHO, because (optional) part of the OAuth flow is using the `state` parameter to check against the value stored in the session, to prevent XSRF attacks on the login flow ...

Comment: @CBroe you were absolutely right. Session do exists. It is only that some legacy code deletes the session just before it redirects to the authenticating server. Bunch of log entries in the code helps me to figure that out.
Thanx a lot for your generous and valuable thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually due to some black magic legacy codes that destroys and regenerating the session right before redirecting to the auth-server. Session do remains after the redirection.

If you have cookie configuration for same_site to `none` or `lax` it session will persists even after external redirection.